# org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: illegal character when i using HtmlUnit

Tags: java, http-unit

I am using the [HttpUnit](http://httpunit.sourceforge.net) to simulate the submit button click of the form that designed into the specified url. (I am using `http://stu21.kntu.ac.ir/Login.aspx`). I use the code as follow to get response page.

```
    WebConversation conversation = new WebConversation();
    WebRequest request = new GetMethodWebRequest("http://stu21.kntu.ac.ir/Login.aspx");
    WebResponse response = conversation.getResource(request);       

    WebForm loginForm = response.getForms()[0]; //Form has been got successfully
    request = loginForm.getRequest();
    request.setParameter("txtusername", "8810103" );
    request.setParameter("txtpassword", "8810103" );
    response = conversation.getResponse( request ); //error while getting the .js files
```

It gets the form successfully, but when i fill out the form and want to submit my form, the error occurred as follow :

> org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: illegal character  at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.DefaultErrorReporter.runtimeError(DefaultErrorReporter.java:98)
>     at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.DefaultErrorReporter.error(DefaultErrorReporter.java:85)
>     at org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.addError(Parser.java:126)  at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.TokenStream.getToken(TokenStream.java:810)     at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.peekToken(Parser.java:144)  at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.primaryExpr(Parser.java:1953)   at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.memberExpr(Parser.java:1641)    at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.unaryExpr(Parser.java:1507)     at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.mulExpr(Parser.java:1436)   at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.addExpr(Parser.java:1417)   at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.shiftExpr(Parser.java:1397)     at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.relExpr(Parser.java:1371)   at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.eqExpr(Parser.java:1327)    at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.bitAndExpr(Parser.java:1316)    at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.bitXorExpr(Parser.java:1305)    at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.bitOrExpr(Parser.java:1294)     at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.andExpr(Parser.java:1282)   at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.orExpr(Parser.java:1270)    at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.condExpr(Parser.java:1253)  at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.assignExpr(Parser.java:1235)    at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.expr(Parser.java:1224)  at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.statementHelper(Parser.java:1111)   at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.statement(Parser.java:623)  at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.parse(Parser.java:355)  at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.Parser.parse(Parser.java:293)  at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.Context.compileImpl(Context.java:2238)     at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.Context.compileString(Context.java:1284)   at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.Context.compileString(Context.java:1273)   at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.Context.evaluateString(Context.java:1129)  at
>   com.meterware.httpunit.javascript.ScriptingEngineImpl.runScript(ScriptingEngineImpl.java:92)
>     at
>   com.meterware.httpunit.scripting.ScriptableDelegate.runScript(ScriptableDelegate.java:88)
>     at
>   com.meterware.httpunit.parsing.NekoDOMParser.runScript(NekoDOMParser.java:151)
>     at
>   com.meterware.httpunit.parsing.ScriptFilter.getTranslatedScript(ScriptFilter.java:150)
>     at
>   com.meterware.httpunit.parsing.ScriptFilter.endElement(ScriptFilter.java:131)
>     at
>   org.cyberneko.html.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:249)
>     at
>   org.cyberneko.html.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:367)
>     at
>   org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1015)
>     at
>   org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:888)
>     at
>   org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$SpecialScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2831)
>     at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:809)
>     at
>   org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:478)
>     at
>   org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:431)
>     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.meterware.httpunit.parsing.NekoHTMLParser.parse(NekoHTMLParser.java:48)
>     at com.meterware.httpunit.HTMLPage.parse(HTMLPage.java:271)     at
>   com.meterware.httpunit.WebResponse.getReceivedPage(WebResponse.java:1301)
>     at
>   com.meterware.httpunit.WebResponse.getFrames(WebResponse.java:1285)
>     at
>   com.meterware.httpunit.WebResponse.getFrameRequests(WebResponse.java:1024)
>     at
>   com.meterware.httpunit.FrameHolder.updateFrames(FrameHolder.java:179)
>     at
>   com.meterware.httpunit.WebWindow.updateFrameContents(WebWindow.java:315)
>     at
>   com.meterware.httpunit.WebClient.updateFrameContents(WebClient.java:526)
>     at com.meterware.httpunit.WebWindow.updateWindow(WebWindow.java:201)
>     at
>   com.meterware.httpunit.WebWindow.getSubframeResponse(WebWindow.java:183)
>     at com.meterware.httpunit.WebWindow.getResponse(WebWindow.java:158)
>     at com.meterware.httpunit.WebWindow.updateWindow(WebWindow.java:199)
>     at
>   com.meterware.httpunit.WebWindow.getSubframeResponse(WebWindow.java:183)
>     at com.meterware.httpunit.WebWindow.getResponse(WebWindow.java:158)
>     at com.meterware.httpunit.WebWindow.updateWindow(WebWindow.java:199)
>     at
>   com.meterware.httpunit.WebWindow.getSubframeResponse(WebWindow.java:183)
>     at com.meterware.httpunit.WebWindow.getResponse(WebWindow.java:158)
>     at com.meterware.httpunit.WebClient.getResponse(WebClient.java:122)
>     at Main.main(Main.java:76) Exception in thread "main"
>   com.meterware.httpunit.ScriptException: Script 'ï»¿var shuffleArray =
>   new Array(); //var field = ""; shuffle = function (o) { //v1.0
>
> ```
> for (var j, x, l = o.length; l; j = parseInt(Math.random() * l), x = o[--l], o[l] = o[j], o[j] = x);
> for (var H = 0; H < 10; H++) {
>     shuffleArray[H] = o[H];
> }
> return o; }
> ```
>
> ////////////////////////////////Key Pad Script function KeyPadInit() {
>       alert("yes");
>       var randomnumber;
>       var myNumbers = new Array();
>
> ```
> for (jj = 0; jj < 10; jj++) {
>     randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
>     while (IsInArray(myNumbers, randomnumber) == 1) {
>         randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
>     };
>     switch (jj) {
>         case 0: document.getElementById('btnSeven0').value = randomnumber; break;
>         case 1: document.getElementById('btnSeven1').value = randomnumber; break;
>         case 2: document.getElementById('btnSeven2').value = randomnumber; break;
>         case 3: document.getElementById('btnSeven3').value = randomnumber; break;
>         case 4: document.getElementById('btnSeven4').value = randomnumber; break;
>         case 5: document.getElementById('btnSeven5').value = randomnumber; break;
>         case 6: document.getElementById('btnSeven6').value = randomnumber; break;
>         case 7: document.getElementById('btnSeven7').value = randomnumber; break;
>         case 8: document.getElementById('btnSeven8').value = randomnumber; break;
>         case 9: document.getElementById('btnSeven9').value = randomnumber; break;
>     }
>     myNumbers[myNumbers.length] = randomnumber;
> }
> ```
>
> }
>
> function IsInArray(objArray, num) {
>       for (i = 0; i <= objArray.length - 1; i++) {
>           if (objArray[i] == num)
>               return 1;
>       }
>       return 0; }
>
> function ChangeStyle(objbtn, action) {
>
> ```
> if (action == 'out') {
>     objbtn.className = 'PadStyle';
> }
> else if (action == 'over') {
>     objbtn.className = 'PadStyleOver';
> }
> ```
>
> }
>
> var inpId = new Array(); var shuffleArray = new Array();
>
> //*****************************************Comput the number of Input
>   box*************************************************** fillArray =
>   function () {
>       inpId.splice(0, inpId.length - 1);
>       var i = 0;
>       var InputsId = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
>       for (var k = 0; k < InputsId.length; k++) {
>           if ((InputsId[k].type == "text") || (InputsId[k].type == "password") || (InputsId[k].type == "checkbox") || (InputsId[k].type
>   == "submit")) {
>               if (!(InputsId[k].disabled)) {
>                   inpId[i++] = InputsId[k];
>               }
>           }
>       } }
>
> function AmountMaskE2(amount) {
>       var i, j, mystring, flag;
>
> ```
> if (amount == '')
>     return "";
>
> i = amount.length;
>
>
> mystring = "";
> for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
>     if (amount.substring(j, j + 1) == ",") {
>         flag = true;
>     }
> }
>
> if (flag == true) {
>     amount = DAmountMaskE(amount);
> }
> i = amount.length;
> if (i > 3) {
>     for (j = i; j > 0; j = j - 3) {
>
>         if (j > 3) {
>             mystring = "," + amount.substring(j - 3, j) + mystring;
>
>         } else {
>             mystring = amount.substring(0, j) + mystring;
>         }
>     }
>
>     return mystring;
> } else {
>
>     return amount;
> }
> ```
>
> }
>
> function DAmountMaskE(amount) {
>       var i, j, mystring, str;
>       i = amount.length;
>       mystring = "";
>
> ```
> for (j = i; j >= 0; j -= 1) {
>     str = amount.substring(j, j - 1);
>     if (str != ",") {
>         mystring = str + mystring;
>     }
> }
> return mystring; }' failed: org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: illegal character  at
> ```
>
> com.meterware.httpunit.javascript.ScriptingEngineImpl.handleScriptException(ScriptingEngineImpl.java:64)
>     at
>   com.meterware.httpunit.javascript.ScriptingEngineImpl.runScript(ScriptingEngineImpl.java:95)
>     at
>   com.meterware.httpunit.scripting.ScriptableDelegate.runScript(ScriptableDelegate.java:88)
>     at
>   com.meterware.httpunit.parsing.NekoDOMParser.runScript(NekoDOMParser.java:151)
>     at
>   com.meterware.httpunit.parsing.ScriptFilter.getTranslatedScript(ScriptFilter.java:150)
>     at
>   com.meterware.httpunit.parsing.ScriptFilter.endElement(ScriptFilter.java:131)
>     at
>   org.cyberneko.html.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:249)
>     at
>   org.cyberneko.html.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:367)
>     at
>   org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1015)
>     at
>   org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:888)
>     at
>   org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$SpecialScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2831)
>     at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:809)
>     at
>   org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:478)
>     at
>   org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:431)
>     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.meterware.httpunit.parsing.NekoHTMLParser.parse(NekoHTMLParser.java:48)
>     at com.meterware.httpunit.HTMLPage.parse(HTMLPage.java:271)     at
>   com.meterware.httpunit.WebResponse.getReceivedPage(WebResponse.java:1301)
>     at
>   com.meterware.httpunit.WebResponse.getFrames(WebResponse.java:1285)
>     at
>   com.meterware.httpunit.WebResponse.getFrameRequests(WebResponse.java:1024)
>     at
>   com.meterware.httpunit.FrameHolder.updateFrames(FrameHolder.java:179)
>     at
>   com.meterware.httpunit.WebWindow.updateFrameContents(WebWindow.java:315)
>     at
>   com.meterware.httpunit.WebClient.updateFrameContents(WebClient.java:526)
>     at com.meterware.httpunit.WebWindow.updateWindow(WebWindow.java:201)
>     at
>   com.meterware.httpunit.WebWindow.getSubframeResponse(WebWindow.java:183)
>     at com.meterware.httpunit.WebWindow.getResponse(WebWindow.java:158)
>     at com.meterware.httpunit.WebWindow.updateWindow(WebWindow.java:199)
>     at
>   com.meterware.httpunit.WebWindow.getSubframeResponse(WebWindow.java:183)
>     at com.meterware.httpunit.WebWindow.getResponse(WebWindow.java:158)
>     at com.meterware.httpunit.WebWindow.updateWindow(WebWindow.java:199)
>     at
>   com.meterware.httpunit.WebWindow.getSubframeResponse(WebWindow.java:183)
>     at com.meterware.httpunit.WebWindow.getResponse(WebWindow.java:158)
>     at com.meterware.httpunit.WebClient.getResponse(WebClient.java:122)
>     at Main.main(Main.java:76)

Can any one give me a solution to solve my problem ?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of the same question asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914232/i-characters-has-occurred-an-error-when-i-use-the-httpunit).

Comment: A simple JUnit test showing how an illegal character breaks down the Javascript handling of httpunit would be helpful. I am httpunit Committer and will happily work on the issue if you supply such a Unit test.

Comment: I have the same error. How did you solve this problem?