# ï»¿ characters has occurred an error when i use the HttpUnit

Tags: java, http-unit

I am using the HttpUnit to simulate the submit button click of the form that designed into the specified url. (I am using http://stu21.kntu.ac.ir/Login.aspx). I use the code as follow to get response page.

```
WebConversation conversation = new WebConversation();
WebRequest request = new GetMethodWebRequest("http://stu21.kntu.ac.ir/Login.aspx");
WebResponse response = conversation.getResource(request);       

WebForm loginForm = response.getForms()[0]; //Form has been got successfully
request = loginForm.getRequest();
request.setParameter("txtusername", "8810103" );
request.setParameter("txtpassword", "8810103" );
response = conversation.getResponse( request ); //error while getting the .js
```

It has the problem when wants to get the java script file, and error is

> Exception in thread "main" com.meterware.httpunit.ScriptException:
>   Script 'ï»¿var shuffleArray = new Array();

So, how can i get rid of this problem ? It prevents my program to load the result page.

Comment: It looks like there are some invalid characters in your public.js file. It is probably the 'Byte Order Marker'. Perhaps you need to set an encoding type?

Comment: How can i set the encoding-type ? :-/

Comment: I'm not an HTTPUnit expert but looking at the [docs](http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/doc/api/com/meterware/httpunit/HttpUnitOptions.html) you should be able to specify `setDefaultCharacterSet` on the `HTTPUnitOptions` as `UTF-8`.

Comment: Great :) Thank you very much, it works well :) Please post your comment as Answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JS file (public.js) has a 'Byte Order Marker'. By default `HTTPUnit` will access pages in [ISO-8859-1](http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/doc/api/com/meterware/httpunit/HttpUnitOptions.html#setDefaultCharacterSet%28java.lang.String%29). By calling `setDefaultCharacterSet` in the `HTTPUnitOptions` and updating the character set to `UTF-8`, `HTTPUnit` will interpret the request as `UTF-8`, provided that there wasn't a Character Set specified on the request to start with. Some more examples of the use of HTTPUnit can be found [here](http://massapi.com/class/ge/GetMethodWebRequest.html).

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) it's UTF-8 Byte Order Mark in ISO-8859-1 representation. You should remove it with text-editor( e.g. Notepad++).

Comment: I can not access the java script file. HttpUnit download and use the .js file!